# Git branch naming to show parent branch

Tags: git, branch, naming

Suppose I have two main branches: `master` and `dev`. All of my development efforts are branched off of `dev` then merged back into `dev`, then eventually into releases then merged into `master`. I would like to name `dev` sub-branches with a `dev/` prefix to show what they were branched from, so perhaps these are some branches:

- `master`
- `dev`
- `dev/new-feature`
- `dev/improved-thing`
- `dev/more-cowbell`

But I cannot do this, instead getting the error:

```
error: unable to create directory for .git/refs/heads/dev/new-feature
fatal: Failed to lock ref for update: No such file or directory
```

Presumably this is because `dev` is an actual branch. Is there a way to make this work, or is there a better way to show this in the branch name? Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are asking for unfortunately cannot work because Git refs are stored in a directory structure (unless you use `pack-refs` to store the refs in a single file), and the reflogs are always stored in a directory structure.

This being the case, you cannot have a file name that is the same as a directory.

Since Git sometimes allows for partial branch names based on `/`, e.g., the `--branches=` option of `git log`, it is NOT optimal to separate based on underscore.

Therefore, as a workaround for your situation I would suggest having a `dev/main` branch instead of just plain `dev`.

Comment: `dev/main` is a great idea. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Open the '.git' folder and go to the folder 'refs/heads'. Here, you should find the file 'dev' which correspond to the branch with the same name. 
When you try to create a branch 'dev/new-feature', git try to create the 'dev' folder to create the 'new-feature' file inside. It can't create the folder because a file have already the same name.

So,you will understand that it's impossible :-(